Call AppIntent in SwiftUI Widget manually
I've created a LiveActivityWidget. It has button which fires LiveActivityIntent in main app. All works fine, but i need to perform other actions inside widget alongside firing Intent.
Button(intent: PlayIntent()) {
    Image(systemName: "play")
}

I don't know how to call intent manually so i can't put it inside action and every action on button inside widget just opens main app.
Ideally i need something like this:
Button(action: {
    callAppIntent(intent: PlayIntent())
    someOtherPrivateWidgetFunction();

}) {
    Image(systemName: "play")
}


Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this is what you're looking for: func perform() async throws -> Self.PerformResult

Performs the intent after resolving the provided parameters.

So you'd call your intent like this:
Task {
    do {
        let intent = PlayIntent()
        try await intent.perform()
        someOtherPrivateWidgetFunction()
    }catch {
        //handle the errors.
    }
}


it seemingly doesn't do anything except default action which is just opening main app

What do you expect it to do?

im sending intent to app that doing something and sending state back to LiveActivity. than LiveActivity changes its view. the problem it that it takes too long and activity feels unresponsive. i was trying to change it internal state alongside with sending intent so view updates independently of main app

You can't update Live Activities from outside the app as wrappers like @State don't work. How are you trying to update it?

well i've read deeper into documentation and you right. widgets can't have state

How did you fix it? Using the TimeLine?
